# issues displaying shoutcast xml data on webpage

Tags: server, apache2, php, xml

I'm lost with how to manipulate xml data. I want to use some data from my shoutcast statistics page. I can access it by going to `http://address:port/statistics`

I cant seem to find a way to access this from the page  I'm creating/modifying. I posted a little while ago with problems accessing mysql but ended up figuring that out with a little help from a comment so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
[image]

```
<a href="javascript:songinfo(<?php echo $comingSong->ID; ?>)" title="<?php echo $comingSong->artist_title; ?>">
<?php echo $comingSong->title; ?>
<?php if(!empty($comingSong->artist)) : ?> <br />by <?php echo $comingSong->artist; ?> <?php endif; ?>
</a>
<?php if($comingSong->isRequested): ?>
    ~requested~
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" colspan="2">

         <!-- this is broken in the program -->

        <?php if (!empty($currentSong) && $currentSong->listeners > 0): ?>
        <div id="listener_count">Listening: <br /><?php echo $currentSong->listeners; ?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>

         <!-- I need to access shoutcastaddress:port/statistics xml file 
         and print the <CURRENTLISTENERS></CURRENTLISTENERS> value here
         to replace the code/value that the program no longer supplies. 
         haven't had any luck -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

I have searched but I cant find anything that shows any sign of connecting or getting the xml data. I have tried code on w3school XML Tutorial but cant seem to find anything that "fits" all their code shows "files" (example.xml) even the ones that supposedly call from a URL. They still show /example.xml (with the xml extension).. but shoutcast doesn't have a .xml .. it just has a "statistics" I tried both `http://shoutcast:port/statistics` and `http://shoutcast:port/statistics.xml` but with using their code a cant get any output. I really don't want to give my servers info out but if anyone wants to figure out something and want to test it they can use this server .. I got it from shoutcasts page .. it's a public station. `https://hazel.torontocast.com:2280/statistics`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of struggling and figuring out new security stuff I didn't know about I was finally able to get some sort of activity. I then did all kinds of research and winded up going in a completely different direction. I found out that shoutcast supplies a file on their servers called 7.html. I decided to use this instead of the xml output. The code my not be the prettiest or best way to accomplish this but it works.
[image]

```
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" colspan="2">
                <?php require_once('../config/shoutcast-conf.php');
                      $conn = array(
                          'http'=>array(
                                'method'=>"GET",
                                'header'=>"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" 
                                )
                        );
                        $context = stream_context_create($conn);
                        $stats = file_get_contents('https://' . $site . ':' . $port . '/7.html', false, $context);
                        $split = preg_split("/[,]+/", $stats, 7);
                        $listeners = $split[0];
                        ?>
                        <span class="auto-style4">Listening:</span> <?php echo $listeners ?> 
        </td>
```

this may be useful to someone. With this you have access to the following stats:
Current Listeners: $split[0],
Available Streams: $split[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWjz7.png),
Peak Listeners: $split[2],
Max Users: $split[3],
Unique Listeners: $split[4],
Bitrate: $split[5] and
Artist - Song: $split[6]